# How can i insert multiple products from the shopping cart into the database as individual rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I am a beginner on this and i apologize in advance. I've been surfing all night long trying to find the answer for my question. Then i saw this platform for programmers.

Here's my problem, My Function are working really fine. I have this shopping cart and user choose many products and submit it. But it only inserting one value to my database. Can anyone help me?

**shopping_cart**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Shopping_cart extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {

        $this->load->model("shopping_cart_model");
        $data["product"] = $this->shopping_cart_model->fetch_all();
        $this->load->view("shopping_cart", $data);

        if (isset($_POST['submitbtn'])) {

            $data = array(
                    "product_name"  => $_POST["cart_name"],
                    "quantity"  => $_POST["cart_qty"],
                    "product_price"  => $_POST["cart_price"]
                );

            $this->db->insert('occasion', $data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "Your account has been 
        reserved");
            redirect("shopping_cart","refresh");    

        }
    }

    function add()
    {
        $this->load->library("cart");
        $data = array(
                  "id"  => $_POST["product_id"],
                  "name"  => $_POST["product_name"],
                   "qty"  => $_POST["quantity"],
                   "price"  => $_POST["product_price"]
                  );
        $this->cart->insert($data); //return rowid 
        echo $this->view();
    }

    function load()
    {
        echo $this->view();
    }

    function remove()
    {
        $this->load->library("cart");
        $row_id = $_POST["row_id"];
        $data = array(
                'rowid'  => $row_id,
                'qty'  => 0
            );
        $this->cart->update($data);
        echo $this->view();
    }

    function clear()
    {
        $this->load->library("cart");
        $this->cart->destroy();
        echo $this->view();
    }

    function view()
    {
        $this->load->library("cart");
        $output = '';
        $output .= '
        <h3>Shopping Cart</h3><br />
             <div class="table-responsive">
             <div align="right">
             <button type="button" id="clear_cart" class="btn btn-warning">Clear 
             Cart</button>
             </div>
             <br />
             <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
             <th width="40%">Name</th>
             <th width="15%">Quantity</th>
             <th width="15%">Price</th>
             <th width="15%">Total</th>
             <th width="15%">Action</th>
            </tr>';
        $count = 0;
        foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items)
        {
            $count++;
            $output .= '
                <tr> 
                <td>'.$items["name"].' <input type="hidden" id="cart_name" name="cart_name" value="'.$items["name"].'" /></td>
                 <td>'.$items["qty"].' <input type="hidden" id="cart_qty" name="cart_qty" value="'.$items["qty"].'" /></td>
                  <td>'.$items["price"].' <input type="hidden" id="cart_price" name="cart_price" value="'.$items["price"].'" /></td>
                 <td>'.$items["subtotal"].'</td>
                  <td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_inventory" id="'.$items["rowid"].'">Remove</button></td>
                  </tr>
                  ';
        }
        $output .= '
               <tr>
               <td colspan="4" align="right">Total</td>
               <td>'.$this->cart->total().'</td>
                </tr>
               </table>

             </div>
             ';

        if($count == 0)
        {
            $output = '<h3 align="center">Cart is Empty</h3>';
        }
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with `[oracle]` if you're really using MySQL,

Comment: In modern PHP shoudln't properties and methods be tagged with a visibility prefix like `public`

Comment: Should we assume you are talking about your `add()` method?

Comment: We would need to see what your form HTML looked like to know how the user adds more than one thing to the cart#

Comment: It looks to me like the add() function is intended to be called every time the user adds something to the cart. Does the UI actually support allowing the user to select several things and only then add all of them to the cart? That would be very unusual.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $data = array(
            "product_name"   => $_POST["cart_name"],
            "quantity"       => $_POST["cart_qty"],
            "product_price"  => $_POST["cart_price"]
    );

    $this->db->insert('occasion', $data);
```

1) assuming you validate the shopping cart with $_POST['submitbtn']  It looks like you're just inserting one product.

2) Why are you receiving product from $_POST if you already store them in card library ?

Maybe this could help :

```
foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items)
 {
   $data = array(

        "product_name"   => $items["name"],
        "quantity"       => $items["qty"],
        "product_price"  => $items["price"]

    );
    $this->db->insert('occasion', $data);
  }
```